# RxJS 5 Timed Cache

Tags: caching, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to get time expiry cache to work for an observable that abstracts a "request-response", using `postMessage` and `message` events on the window.

The remote window expects a message `getItemList` and replies to it with a message of type `{type: 'itemList', data: []}`.

I would like to model the `itemList$` observable in such a way that it caches the last result for 3 seconds, so that no new requests are made during that time, however, I cannot think of a way to achieve that in an elegant (read, one observable – no subjects) and succint manner.

Here is the example in code:

```
const remote = someIframe.contentWindow;
const getPayload = message => message.data;
const ofType = type => message => message.type === type;

// all messages coming in from the remote iframe
const messages$ = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'message')
  .map(getPayload)
  .map(JSON.parse);

// the observable of (cached) items
const itemList$ = Observable.defer(() => {
    console.log('sending request');

    // sending a request here, should happen once every 3 seconds at most
    remote.postMessage('getItemList');

    // listening to remote messages with the type `itemList`
    return messages$
      .filter(ofType('itemList'))
      .map(getPayload);
  })
  .cache(1, 3000);

/**
 * Always returns a promise of the list of items
 * @returns {Promise<T>}
 */
function getItemList() {
  return itemList$
    .first()
    .toPromise();
}


// poll every second
setInterval(() => {
  getItemList()
    .then(response => console.log('got response', response));
}, 1000);
```

I am aware of [the (very similar) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475317/how-to-implement-time-expiry-hot-observable-in-rxjs-or-general-in-reactive-exte), but I am wondering if anyone can come up with a solution without explicit subjects.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like `.repeat()` tacked onto the end of `itemList$` does the trick. Can anyone confirm that this is the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the rxjs operator **throttle**:

[Documentation on rxjs github repo](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md)

> Returns an Observable that emits only the first item emitted by the
>   source Observable during sequential time windows of a specified
>   duration.

Basically, if you would like to wait until the inputs have quieted for a certain period of time before taking action, you want to **debounce**.

If you do not want to wait at all, but do not wish to make more than 1 query within a specific amount of time, you will want to **throttle**. From your use case, I think you want to **throttle**