# RxJS - How to share the output of an expensive observable but rerun that observable if its requested again after N seconds?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs6

Let's say we have this global const:

```js
const isSignedIn = fromPromise(fetch('/api/is-signed-in'))
    .pipe(throttleTime(1000), shareReply(1));
```

After page load, several components will subscribe to this at the same time:

```js
isSignedIn.subscribe(() => console.log('do 1st'));
isSignedIn.subscribe(() => console.log('do 2nd'));
isSignedIn.subscribe(() => console.log('do 3rd'));
```

The above will only call the API once, however i need it to call the API again (ie after 1 second) if another component subscribes to it.

```js
isSignedIn.subscribe(() => console.log('button press'));
```

How do i that using RxJS?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/operators/refCountDelay.ts and its associated tests.

Comment: you might want to reimplement that example in another streams library, and see if the behaviour you get from rxjs is the same as in, say bacon.js, or most, if the other libraries perform as expected, then this issue might be related on RxJS producing `cold` streams, and that might help you refine your google queries. And take this comment with a grain of salt, it's been a long time since I've used RxJS.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

#### A pipeable operator (declare globally somewhere and import it)

```
 export const refreshAfter = (duration: number) => (source: Observable<any>) =>
                             source.pipe(
                                   repeatWhen(obs => obs.pipe(delay(duration))),
                                   publishReplay(1), 
                                   refCount());
```

Then use it like this:

```
data$ = fetch('/api/is-signed-in').pipe(refreshAfter(5000));   // refresh after 5000 ms
```

---

Note: You actually asked for this:

> i need it to call the API again (ie after 1 second) if another component subscribes to 
>   it.

Not quite sure this is what you really meant. I think what you really meant was  - you want the data to be refreshed **for all components currently subscribed after an expiry time**. Anyway my answer sends the new value to all listeners. If you really want what you originally said you'd need to add some kind of alternative repeat trigger.

But if this is for a global constant - the above is what I'm using for the same scenario.

Note: I haven't actually tested the handling of an error condition when the item is repested, but I think the error will propagate to all listeners.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: The answer is wrong. BufferSize is how long the last N events are replayed. After this the stream is completed.

```
signature: shareReplay(
  bufferSize?: number,
  windowTime?: number,
  scheduler?: IIScheduler
):Observable

@param {Number} [bufferSize=Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY] Maximum element count of the replay buffer.
@param {Number} [windowTime=Number.MAX_VALUE] Maximum time length of the replay buffer in milliseconds.
```

Try to add `1000` as second argument to shareReply:

```
const isSignedIn = fromPromise(fetch('/api/is-signed-in'))
    .pipe(throttleTime(1000), shareReplay(1, 1000));
```

[shareReplay.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/shareReplay.ts) - be care of `refCount--` on unsubcribe as it can trigger additional requests.

Comment: `shareReplay` might not behave quite as you expect. Have a look at https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4059

Comment: why would you put throttleTime and ALSO a windowTime?

Comment: @cartant, this issue definitely causes issues. it is supposed to be 'fixed' soon with additional parameters to shareReplay. See my answer for example using publishReplay(1).refCount() instead

Comment: @Simon It should be included the next release - which, hopefully, will be next week. Note, though, that the default behaviour will **still** be to not reference count. Also, `publishReplay(1).refCount()` won't be quite the same, as any error will be replayed, rather than effecting another subscription to the source.

Comment: @cartant Thanks - I just added my answer to this (after your previous comment). I create a pipeable operator that repeats after a time duration, then publishReplay / refCounts it. I'll have to revisit this later because I've already spent half the afternoon correcting my assumptions about how shareReplay works! If you have any thoughts on how to improve my answer with that in mine I'd love to see it. I suppose the desired behavior would depend upon what the value being cached actually is. Maybe catchError and pipe to EMPTY :-/ Fine for a trivial constant, but not a stock quote!

Comment: so I think this is correct: `shareReplay({ newVersion: true })` will NOT 'cache' errors, and retry the source on every subscription. Whereas `publishReplay(1).refCount()` gets 'stuck' and literally returns a cached error until the refresh time window has expired?

Answer (score 0):

If we reimplement ShareReplay so it:
- will never unsubscribe from source even if it have no more subscribers (remove refCount, potential memory leak).
 - accept rerunAfter argument, time passed from last `subscribe` to source.

```
import {Subject, of, Observable, ReplaySubject, Subscriber} from 'rxjs';
import {pluck, shareReplay, tap, delay} from 'rxjs/operators';

function shareForeverReplayRerun<T>(bufferSize: number, rerunAfter: number) {
  let subject;
  let subscription;
  let hasError = false;
  let isComplete = false;
  let lastSubTime = 0;

  return source => Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<T>) => {
    if (!subject || hasError || (Date.now() - lastSubTime) >= rerunAfter) {

      lastSubTime = Date.now();
      hasError = false;
      subject = new ReplaySubject<T>(bufferSize);
      subscription = source.subscribe({
        next(value) { subject.next(value); },
        error(err) {
          hasError = true;
          subject.error(err);
        },
        complete() {
          isComplete = true;
          subject.complete();
        },
      });
    }

    const innerSub = subject.subscribe(observer);
    // never unsubscribe from source
    return () => {
      innerSub.unsubscribe();
    };
  })
}





const source = of('Initial').pipe(
  tap(()=>console.log('COMPUTE')),
  delay(200),
  shareReplayRerun(1, 1000),
);

source.subscribe(console.log.bind(null, 'syncI:'));
source.subscribe(console.log.bind(null, 'syncII:'));

setTimeout(()=>source.subscribe(console.log.bind(null, 'after500:')), 500);

setTimeout(()=>source.subscribe(console.log.bind(null, 'after900:')), 900);

setTimeout(()=>source.subscribe(console.log.bind(null, 'after1500:')), 1500);
```

as output we have:

```
COMPUTE
syncI:    Initial
syncII:   Initial
after500: Initial
after900: Initial
COMPUTE
after1500:Initial
```